# Bitnami Tomcat Stack Maven fails to compile

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, bitnami

Used Bitnami Tomcat Stack to create a instance in EC2 . Everything works perfect in matter of few mins. But at final stage to deploy application maven is failing to compile the source code. Eventhoug JAVA_HOME is perfectly set it is failing to compile with below error log.

```
root@ip-172-31-18-89:/mnt/apps/stutzen-backend# echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/bitnami/java
root@ip-172-31-18-89:/mnt/webapps/stutzen-backend# mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ware27 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ ware27 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ ware27 ---
[INFO] Compiling 34 source files to /mnt/webapps/stutzen-backend/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  /opt/bitnami/java/../lib/tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.245s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jul 13 10:37:54 UTC 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/25M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ware27: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] /opt/bitnami/java/../lib/tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

How to deal with it ?

Comment: what is your JAVA_HOME?did you check  "/opt/bitnami/java/../lib/tools.jar" ?

Comment: as per bitnami tomcat stack javahome is /opt/bitnami/java . the correct path for tools.jar is "/opt/bitnami/java/lib/tools.jar" , but cant understand why it is picking "/opt/bitnami/java/../lib/tools.jar"

Comment: check your maven profiles to see if you have any line like:         <toolsjar>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</toolsjar>

Comment: have checked pom.xml, settings.xml and m2.conf . Cant able to find any  text like this. Is there any any other file need to check ?

Comment: Are your java binaries in ${java.home}/bin?

Comment: Yes, binaries are available under /opt/bitnami/java/bin/ , where JAVA_HOME = /opt/bitnami/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the [maven compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) is configured by default to use the a Java 1.5 compiler (see the source and target options in the [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)) while Bitnami Tomcat Stack is includes Java 1.7. You will need to configure your projects to use Java 1.7 instead. For this you can define a different value for the `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` properties or define the `maven.compiler.compilerVersion` instead which will work as well. In both cases you need to set `maven.compiler.fork` to true. The example below shows how to configure this per project:

pom.xml:

```
<project>
(...)
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>1.7</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
    <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
  </properties>
(...)
</project>
```

However you will likely want to define these settings as [global settings](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for all your projects. In that case you can edit the settings.xml in ($M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml) and define a profile which will be always actived:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" ...>
(...)
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>
      <properties>
        <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>1.7</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
        <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>env-dev</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

kaysa's answer is correct. The solution, however, can be achieved a little easier by adding a maven-compiler-plugin to your pom as shown below:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you or not. add a profile to your pom.xml :)

```
   <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default-tools.jar</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>java.vendor</name>
                    <value>Oracle Corporation</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.2</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

give your true tools.jar address and run maven with this profile 
if it's not working forget that and change your java home to something like :  /opt/bitnami/jdk1.7.0_51/jre:)

Comment: Added in POM and executed  "mvn compile -P default-tools.jar" , but same problem. Changed version to 1.7 and systempath to "/opt/bitnami/java/lib/tools.jar"

Comment: :) in that case "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /opt/bitnami/java/jre/bin/java"

Comment: yes it should show this message cuz you didn't install jdk correctly. if you download jdk and extract it you will have jdk/jre/bin/java.

Comment: jdk is part of Bitnami Tomcat Stack, it is not advisable to mess it up. Hope you are new to Bitnami. Just tried with some folder name as hack but it doesnt work out.